# React useState Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I have a component and fetch data from an API (https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all). It is an array of objects.
I want to pass some of the info of that object to a state but it gets stuck in a loop.

```
function AllCountries() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`)
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data!== undefined) {
        
          data.map((ob) => {
          setCountries(
            ...countries,{
            flag: ob.flag,
            name: ob.name,
            population: ob.population,
            region: ob.region,
            capital: ob.capital}
          );
        });
        //console.log(countries);
      } else {
        alert("Can´t Load Data");
      }
    });

  return (
    <div>PRUEBA</div>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: Every time your state changes, the component is re-rendered. That means all of the code you have there is executed again after every change. Since your code is causing a change of state right in the main body of the function, that is why you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be wrapped in `useEffect`:

```
function AllCountries() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`)
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => {
        if (data!== undefined) {
            
            data.map((ob) => {
            setCountries(
                ...countries,{
                flag: ob.flag,
                name: ob.name,
                population: ob.population,
                region: ob.region,
                capital: ob.capital}
            );
            });
            //console.log(countries);
        } else {
            alert("Can´t Load Data");
        }
        });
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>PRUEBA</div>
    
  );
}
```

Otherwise, the `fetch` will get executed every time the component is rendered.

Furthe reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: if a do that, i only get a state with the last element of the complete data...

Comment: @AgustinMiotti yes, because you've got another issue in your code - you should never call setState in a loop. But I have answered your "stuck in infinite loop" question. I'm not sure what your goal is, but I think you want `setCountries(data)`